# Is it possible to unwrap materials made in Vertex Paint?

Tags: uv, vertex-paint

I painted an group of objects in Blender using the Vertex Paint and was wondering if it would be possible to unwrap the mutliple materials(when the objects are joined together using Ctrl+J)? Do I have to paint it all over again?

Comment: Vertex paint is not using UVs, its assigning color values to each vertex, if you join objects vertex paint will remain the same. You can bake vertex colors to a texture when your objects are unwrapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can bake Vertex colors to a texure.

Starting from a vertex color layer as in the picture below

[image]

you must **unwrap** your model (which may consist of one or multiple meshes) and create a new image to bake onto ("untitled" in my case)

[image]

Than go in the **Bake** panel of the Render tab and set Bake mode to Vertex color.

[image]

When the process is completed you should see something like the picture above.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I am looking for. Glad I don't have to repaint everything. :D

Comment: This Baking option only works in Blender Render. But you can easily change to it and get back to Cycles after. :)