# How can I make vertex colours into a UV map image?

Tags: file-format, vertex-colors, uv-image-editor

I've painted my mesh in vertex paint, but I would like to edit the colours in Gimp, then reapply them as a texture and bake back to vertex colours.  Is there a way to export just the vertex colours? So it appears as a image file?

Comment: I don't think exporting UV layout could really help you here.. Bake vertex colors into image and use that one. There's also addon for [baking image information into vertex colors](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Bake_Texture_to_Vertex_Colors).

Comment: I don't have an option to bake vertex colours into image. Only "bake selected to active" and "bake to vertex colour".

Comment: If Blender Internal in Bake panel select Vertex Colors from dropdown list. If Cycles connect output with vertex colors into something like Emit shader and bake Emit. For BI - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35159/is-it-possible-to-unwrap-materials-made-in-vertex-paint. For Cycles - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/how-can-vertex-paint-be-rendered

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I'm looking for. The first link anyway, i'm not sure why you attached the second since I don't have a problem rendering vertex colours. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, switch to blender render engine temporarily to bake out the vertex colors to an image (I won't go into the details of how to bake as there are tons of tuts out there for that).

[image]

Edit the resulting image in Gimp.

[image]

Then setup an image texture in BI and enable bake to vertex color, then bake in "Textures" mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the UV Image editor window ... the menu is available

[image]

In the user preferences window this is available.

[image]

Comment: I confused myself by with the UV export option, sorry (I edited my question). I want to export the vertex colours as an image file.